# Like button throwing error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Like button error since yesterday - URL could not be liked because it's been blocked.

i get this error when i click the like plugin from my actual app canvas page. although i can go to the  actual app page and like the page by hitting the like button on that page.

This error started experiencing from yesterday.  Any help will be much appreciated.

App page- https://www.facebook.com/pages/World-Footie-Manager-Play-Free-Football-Soccer/169765953131927

App canvas page ( where error occurs)- https://apps.facebook.com/worldfootballmanager/

Comment: A link to the page in question or an example of the like button code you are using would be helpful in solving this.